# Linux: How to set default directory of terminal emulators?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, gnome, gnome-terminal, urxvt

After upgrading to Ubuntu 11.04, my terminals (gnome-terminal and urxvt) start in `"/"` instead of `"~"`

**What can cause this behavior?**

I imagine that the working directory of Gnome or X is set to `"/"`, or something like that, but I have no idea on where to start debugging this.

I use zsh, config can be included.

Comment: you could try `dirs -v` to find out whether the last entry comes from some pushd after $HOME in some way.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you see this behavior when opening the terms with custom keyboard shortcuts while they start in the right directory if opened via the menu or the *Run Application* dialog.

Curiously programs you define under the *Custom Shortcuts* section of the Gnome *Keyboard Shortcuts* dialog don't seem to inherit the session working directory. Knowing nothing about the reasons, I suspect this is a bug.

Workarounds:

- Use the *Run a terminal* shortcut in the *Desktop* section and set your preferred terminal emulator under *System* => *Preferences* => *Preferred Applications* => *System* => *Terminal Emulator*,
- Set the keyboard shortcut to a wrapper script, e.g.

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  exec rxvt -cd $HOME
  ```
- Define the shortcut to include setting the working directory, e.g.:

  ```
  gnome-terminal --working-directory=$HOME
  ```

  or

  ```
  rxvt -cd /path/to/home
  ```

  (The latter doesn't work with `$HOME` for me; I had to give the absolute path.)

Comment: 100% Correct! Thanks! I fixed it by using compiz' keyboard shortcuts instead. Very good suggestions. (The run application dialog actually behaves as it should in ubuntu natty)

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem adding a cd command at the end of my ~/.bashrc

```
...
cd /your_desired_path
```

After that, everytime you invoke the console that uses .bashrc will be prompting at your desired path.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to put `cd` at the end of your `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: Zsh is my default shell. Wouldn't this screw up scripts expecting cwd to be something else??

Comment: Scripts expect to be in the home folder at startup.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to check:

1. Your home directory is set properly (cd ~ takes you home ok)
2. The partition that contains your home directory is mounted and usable at the time GDM logs you in.

I had a similar problem using ZFS and having my home on a ZFS pool.  ZFS wasn't starting before GDM so when it logged me in my home dir wasn't there.  A few seconds later it was there though, so I could cd to it.

Comment: Good suggestions! 1: If i login outside X, everything works, so it seems that $HOME at least is correct there. "echo $HOME" is also correct in the terminal emulators. 2: I've tried restarting GDM after making sure everything's mounted, without luck :(